# How to detect MIME type error in Angular 9 app and get notified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ecmascript-6

I had the MIME type error `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-javascript mime type of text/html` earlier in my Angular app and I got it resolved.

However, I am unable to find a way on how to get notified of this error if it might happen again.

I'm using Sentry to detect errors in my Angular app to get notified of any errors. In this case, the MIME error pops up even before the `main` module is loaded where sentry is also initialized.
In fact, the error means it is unable to find/load the `main` module.

Due to this issue, a blank white screen was shown by the browser and my production website was unusable for some time. There were no build issues.

1. How can I detect and get alerted about this error if it ever happens again?
2. Are there any external tools available that can monitor my application for such errors and notify me?
3. What are the best practices currently being followed in the industry?

Comment: You may want to require an application stabilization signal to occur in some amount of time after page load if it doesn't you would have to initialize sentry outside of angular context and report an error.

Comment: @Xesenix But where can I trigger this app stabilization signal from? Even if server listens for this signal, how does it know there was a page load happened in someone's browser?

Comment: you can start listening on first stabilization event combining https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER with https://lukaonik.medium.com/demystifying-the-applicationref-isstable-event-in-angular-20c546fe617e this would get you to the point when application signals everything ok but you would still have to implement some script outside of angular that would listen for whatever signal you send from there I would advise using some postMessage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage on which you would wait in that outside script

Answer (score 0):

most of the time this error happens if the browser got TypeScript instead of JS file